# Google UiApp, concurrency, LockService and the rabbit-hole

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm working on a methodology which reliably executes single or multiple function asyncronously. I've had reasonable success, but there were lingering issues with ensuring that the call-stack was fully executed in series for batches. The theory is still not water-tight, but to my estimation it should perform better than it is.

There are 3 functions (with some superfluous ones which you can remove for testing purposes):

1. asyncFunctionLaunch - is called in-line to introduce a new function set (key) into the call stack. each key can contain 1 or more functions to call, each with a single attribute 'start', which is used to flag that a function has already been called, but may not yet have finished executing. For want of a better idea, the keys are assigned using a derivative of getTime(). tests show the offset addition functionality isn't necessary, but I have it just in case... The function accepts a comma-delimited list of function names. each call to the function creates a new key in the stack, and signifies that the functions passed must be executed in series. keys in the stack however, can be executed in any order.
2. eventExecAsyncFunction - is a callback triggered by the checkbox valuechange event (thanks @Serge for the concept!), and this is what allows async execution of the list members
3. cacheQuickEdit - a 'domesticated' version of a library function I have, which calls other library functions that modify the userCache. You can change those calls for testing purposes; the precedent functions are about 3 lines each & academic.

```js
// INTRODUCE A LIST OF FUNCTIONS TO BE EXECUTED ASYNCRONOUSLY
function asyncFunctionLaunch(Functions, app) {

  var lockRef = LockService.getUserLock();
  var bLock = lockRef.tryLock(10000);

  app = app || UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  Functions = Functions.split(',');
  var vExecList = cacheQuickEdit(CACHEKEY.uiExecAsync);

  var iOffset = 1;
  var batchKey = String(new Date().getTime()) + '001';
  batchKey = parseFloat(batchKey);
  var vThisKey = {};

  if (typeof vExecList != 'undefined') {

    while (vExecList[batchKey]) {
      iOffset++;
      var sPadChar = stringPadLR(iOffset, '0', 3);  // YOU DON'T NEED ALL THIS, A SIMPLE getTime() WILL SUFFICE AS THE KEY INDEX FOR TESTING 
      var batchKey = String(new Date().getTime()) + sPadChar;
      batchKey = parseFloat(batchKey);
    };

    for (var iFunc in Functions) {
      if (typeof vThisKey[Functions[iFunc]] == 'undefined') {

        vThisKey[Functions[iFunc]] = {
          start: false,
        };

      };
    };

  } else {

    vExecList = {};

    for (var iFunc in Functions) {
      vThisKey[Functions[iFunc]] = {
        start: false,
      };
    };

  };

  vExecList[batchKey] = vThisKey;
  cacheQuickEdit(CACHEKEY.uiExecAsync, vExecList);

  var oControl = app.getElementById('chkPreloadTrigger');
  oControl.setValue(false, false);
  oControl.setValue(true, true);

  lockRef.releaseLock();

  return app;
};


// RECURSIVELY EXECUTE CACHED LIST OF FUNCTIONS ASYNCRONOUSLY
function eventExecAsyncFunction(e) {

  var lockRef = LockService.getUserLock();
  var bLock = lockRef.tryLock(50000);

  var sSource = e.parameter.source;
  var vTriggerVal = (e.parameter[sSource] == 'true');    
  //var vTriggerVal = false; // FOR TESTING

  var vExecList = cacheQuickEdit(CACHEKEY.uiExecAsync);

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var oChkPreload = app.getElementById('chkPreloadTrigger');

  if (Object.keys(vExecList).length == 0) {

    oChkPreload.setValue(false, false);
    return app;
  };

  var sExec = '';
  for (var sKey in vExecList) {

    var vExec = vExecList[sKey];
    // TEST FOR KEYS WITH FUNCTIONS BEING EXECUTED
    var bExec = Object.keys(vExec).some(function(el) {
      return (vExec[el].start == true);
    });

    if (bExec == false) {
      // RETURN FIRST FUNCTION FROM KEY HAVING NO EXECUTING MEMBERS
      sExec = Object.keys(vExec)[0];
      break;
    };
  };

  // NO NON-EXECUTING FUNCTIONS FOUND
  if (sExec == '') {

    // WORK FROM START OF KEY LIST   
    loop_exec_list: for (var sKey in vExecList) {
      var vExec = vExecList[sKey];

      for (var iExec in vExec) {

        if (vExec[iExec].start == true) {
          delete vExecList[sKey][iExec];

          if (Object.keys(vExec).length < 1) {
            delete vExecList[sKey];
          };

        } else {

          sExec = Object.keys(vExec)[0];
          break loop_exec_list;
        };

      };
    };

  };

  var iKeys = Object.keys(vExecList).length;
  if (sExec == '') {

    oChkPreload.setValue(false, false);
    lockRef.releaseLock();

    return app;
  };

  vExecList[sKey][sExec].start = true;

  var vNewExec = JSON.stringify(vExecList[sKey]);
  var iFuncs = Object.keys(vExecList[sKey]).length - 1;
  delete vExecList[sKey];

  var iOffset = 1;
  var batchKey = String(new Date().getTime()) + '001';
  batchKey = parseFloat(batchKey);

  while (vExecList[batchKey]) {
    iOffset++;
    var sPadChar = stringPadLR(iOffset, '0', 3);
    var batchKey = String(new Date().getTime()) + sPadChar;
    batchKey = parseFloat(batchKey);
  };

  vExecList[batchKey] = JSON.parse(vNewExec);
  cacheQuickEdit(CACHEKEY.uiExecAsync, vExecList);

  if (iFuncs > 0) { // IF THIS KEY CONTAINS MORE FUNCTIONS, TRIGGER CALLBACK AGAIN
    oChkPreload.setValue(false, false);
    oChkPreload.setValue(true, true);
  };

  lockRef.releaseLock();
  app = this[sExec](app, e);

  return app;
};

function cacheQuickEdit(sTargetCache, vValue) {

  var lockRef = LockService.getUserLock();
  var bLock = lockRef.tryLock(10000);

  switch (true) {
    case (typeof vValue == 'undefined'):

      var vCache = nnGenericFuncLib.cacheLoadObject(sTargetCache);

      if (vCache != null) {
        var vObj = JSON.parse(vCache);
      } else {
        var vObj = {};
      };

      lockRef.releaseLock();
      return vObj;

      break;

    case (vValue == ''):

      nnGenericFuncLib.cacheDeleteObject(sTargetCache);
      lockRef.releaseLock();
      return null;

      break;

    default:

      nnGenericFuncLib.cacheSaveObject(sTargetCache, JSON.stringify(vValue), nnGenericFuncLib.CACHE_TIMEOUT);
      lockRef.releaseLock();
      return sTargetCache;

      break;
  };

  lockRef.releaseLock();
  return false;
};
```

My theory is that the callback allows functions in the stack to execute concurrently because the lock terminates before the call, meaning another function can be loaded for execution before the first returns. I am assuming that each callback occurs within a unique instance, and that there are no conflicts within the callback itself.

The other critical part of the plan is the use of the cache which permits orderly stack execution. The plan is to flag the first function, of the first key in the stack as 'started', then to move that key to the end of the stack, before invoking a new instance of the callback and finally executing the function.

The next invocation again finds the first key containing no functions which have been started, and duplicates the previous process.

When all the keys contain a function which has been flagged as started, the code will again pick the first key in the list, delete the function flagged as started (which will *hopefully* have completed), then follow the first process - and so on, until all the functions, in all the keys have been flagged, executed and deleted.

I have used locks in each of these functions to prevent the cache from being overwritten either in advance or retard.

The basics of all this works, but what I see by (separately) caching the stack on each execution of the callback, is that the chronology is not consistent; it all goes a bit 'quantum', and I end up with too many calls, and not enough executions.

Any thoughts / suggestions welcome!

-- EDIT --
screen-shot of call-stack & sequence after completion

[image]

Comment: Huge question, Tim. Way out of normal scope here, but interesting still. Unfortunately, it will take quite some time to figure out what you're doing, and devise experiments... and at an hourly rate of $0 it just doesn't pay! "I end up with too many calls, and not enough executions." Could you provide the evidence that makes you conclude this? Any help you can give to reduce the investment that people helping you need to make will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mogsdad! and yes, I appreciate it's a bit of a chunky topic, but if it can be won then I think everyone wins as it promises to slash start-up times for UiApp webapps :)
I've attached a screenshot of the state of play once execution ceases. from the webapp, I can see some functions have been executed more than once, and some not at all.

The first stack contains the list of functions which were passed into the routine.

The 2nd stack (collapsed) simply echos that, so is not useful

The 3rd stack (expanded) is a snapshot of the function cache, at each pass into the callback

Comment: The arrow points to what was the first function placed into the stack. Its ending position shows it was processed according to the rules, but that the number of callbacks was insufficient to complete the stack.

Comment: As you can see, the basic premise works, but the chronology seems to be lost along the way since the callback is triggered once for every key in the stack. What's bugging me, is that I had another caching function which worked better, but didn't use the LockService. Now that I'm using the LockService within the caching function, the chronology seems to have been lost - which is completely the opposite to what I expected and intended!

Comment: I just took the LockService calls out of the caching function, and on the face of it, the startup routine executed flawlessly. but examining chache log shows some 40+ executions, with over-writes taking place and other such nasties. my hunch is that the issue is with the logic in my caching function, possibly how it manages the lock. bearing in mind it could be called by the initialising function simultaneously with the execution function - does the internal logic appear solid?

Answer (score 0):

Well it took a couple of days, much wailing & knashing of teeth, and some hair loss but in the end I found out what was going wrong. **Basically the LockService is utterly useless in this context** (easy when you know how), so I had to code my own "concurrency lockService". add another day of more wailing and I'm at last getting reliable results.

I won't post the code I came up with here as it's going to be hard to represent it accurately without a context, and besides, now I have an idea of how to improve it further. But once I do have it all sorted (and have had a couple of days of massage & hair replacement therapy), I'll write a blog on it. let me know it you're interested and I'll post an update on that later :)

Comment: I'm interested in your own concurrent solution pls :-)